# jQuery to cycle through images on button press

Tags: jquery, image, loops, buttonclick

Complete novice at coding so apologies in advance but I'm tearing my hair out about this question!

#### Task at hand

I'm trying to get jQuery to cycle through a set of images upon a button click in an endless loop.

I've got the following so far and I can't find any holes in my logic, but it just doesn't seem to work. If someone could have a quick look over it and maybe put it all into a working jsfiddle I would very much appreciate it!

```
      $(document).ready(function() { 
      $(“#button”).click(function() {

    var src = $('#myimage').attr('src');

    //if the current image is picture1.png, change it to picture2.png
    if(src == 'pic1.png') {
        $("#myimage").attr("src","pic2.png");

    //if the current image is picture2.png, change it to picture3.png 
    } else if(src == "pic2.png") {
        $("#myimage").attr("src","pic3.png"); 

    //if the current image is anything else, change it back to picture1.png
    } else {
        $("#myimage").attr("src","pic1.png");
    }
});
```

UPDATE
I think I may be doing something wrong with my actual fiddle?
https://jsfiddle.net/pj2wvcdx/

Comment: What's wrong with the code you got? Except that you're note closing the click-function properly it seems to be working fine.

Comment: Those first quotes look funny... Did you copy and paste those? Make sure you are using `"`. Also (it could be a typo) you are missing a closing `});`.

Comment: could you please post your HTML and CSS too. That will helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example. It's all based on your code, and the only thing I changed is that you used the wrong quotes for `"#button"`, but that might have been a copy-paste-thing? And you didn't close the `click` function.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#button").click(function() {
    var src = $('#myimage').attr('src');

    //if the current image is picture1.png, change it to picture2.png
    if(src == 'http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/PngSuite/f01n2c08.png') {
        $("#myimage").attr("src","http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/PngSuite/f02n2c08.png");

    //if the current image is picture2.png, change it to picture3.png 
    } else if(src == "http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/PngSuite/f02n2c08.png") {
        $("#myimage").attr("src","http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/PngSuite/f03n2c08.png"); 
    //if the current image is anything else, change it back to picture1.png
    } else {
        $("#myimage").attr("src","http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/PngSuite/f01n2c08.png");
    }
    console.log("Src is: " + $("#myimage").attr("src"));
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button" >Cycle</button>
<img src="http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/PngSuite/f01n2c08.png" id="myimage"/>
```

The error in your snippet is that you're never going from 1 -> 2.

[image]

Comment: I think I may be doing something wrong with my actual fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/pj2wvcdx/

Comment: I've updated my snippet based on the images in your fiddle.

Comment: I can't manage to get that to cycle to a third image and then back to the first image, I've messed with the fiddle but I think I've broken it... again. Sorry, any help?

Comment: I've updated my answer, with an answer for your fiddle. ;)